# PHP preg_match_all html tags content search

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a problem, i want to do count of symbols in html tags in text.

**Text example 1:**

```
Hello <b>world</b>, <i>stackoverflow</i>
```

**Text example 2:**

```
Hello <b>world, <i>stackoverflow</i></b>
```

So, I need to count how many symbols in **b** and in **i** block separately.

I did this:

```
preg_match_all('#<(b|i)>(.*)<\/(b)>#Uusi', $temp, $tags_check);

foreach($tags_check[2] as $val)
{
    if(mb_strlen($val) > 50)
    {
        $errors = 'error';
        break;
    }
}
```

But it`s works only for first example, in second example i need to do something with regexp. I need to search on start **b** and on end **b**, but not on start **b** and on end **i**, how can i do this?

Comment: You need to use a DOM parser not regex.

Comment: What functions need to use?

Comment: Perhaps `DOMDocument`

Comment: Use `#(?=<(b|i)>(.*?)</\1>)#is` and `print_r()` it to see the results, thank me later :)

Comment: That`s it! I`d thinking about something like this but didn`t know about \1 in pattern. Thank you!

Comment: Mike Brant, thank you too, domDocument working great, i wiil use it too!

Comment: In the second example, do you want to count for `<b>..</b>` content the size of tags that are inside?

Answer (score 3):

DOM + XPath way to accomplish that:

```
$html = 'Hello <b>world</b>, <i>stackoverflow</i>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$error_nodes = $xpath->query('//b[string-length(text()) > 50]|//i[string-length(text()) > 50]');

foreach ($error_nodes as $node) {
    print $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanx! Another question, i have user html theme parser with custom blocks like {block:Name} hello {/block:Name}, can i use this method to parse it instead of many preg_match_all preg_replace? And is this will be much faster?

Comment: @swamprunner7 You're welcome! Unfortunatelly DOM/XPath works only with HTML/XML-like tags, for these custom blocks perhaps a custom BBCode-like parser would fit better than regular expressions. I don't know any, but I'm sure it already exists... :)